# Is the 30,000 HYDRON COLLIDERS around this planet being used to manipulate Earth's magnetic fields to create eruptions, earthquakes,ECT

Tags: volcanology

Is cern/DARPA using all 30,000 HYDRON COLLIDERS scattered around earth being used to manipulate weather, natural disasters, like activating the 48 volcanoes that are erupting that started at the end of May till present. Each one is a different size baking me think the large HYDRON COLLIDER is the main control of the network of the colliders that may or not be connected to the Darpa field of antennas that manipulate the weather. On YouTube that photos of groups of animals running in circles for 12 days or more without food or water in different continents different states different countries everywhere around the planet there are animals running in circles for days without water or food. Do you have anything to say about that. Because Moses animals run off the Earth's magnetic field of them migrating where they go and the rain is true because they're confused because you guys are pulsating the Earth with the hydron colliders. The animals are all on YouTube. You should check it out it's wild.

Comment: Don't trust everything you see on the internet.  Go outside.  Go drive around.  Are the animals all running around in circles.  No, the weather and volcano activity amount are both fairly similar to what we've seen historically.  We don't have nearly the power, understanding, or ability to alter the Earth on the scale suggested.

Comment: What 30 000 [Hadron colliders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadron_collider)? Only five (5) have been built.

Answer (score 2):

Hadron colliders are [expensive](https://home.cern/resources/faqs/facts-and-figures-about-lhc) to construct and operate. As a consequence only [five have been constructed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadron_collider), not 30 000. The construction cost of the [Large Hadron Collider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider) was 4.332 billion Swiss Francs. One Swiss Franc is about the equivalent of one US Dollar.

Many fanciful stories about hadron colliders have been promulgated by conspiracy theorists and the ignorant.

Prior to the first use of the [Large Hadron Collider](https://www.space.com/large-hadron-collider-particle-accelerator) in 2008 there were [news reports](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20130716-will-we-ever-create-a-black-hole) that the collider would create a [black hole](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2008/10oct_lhc/) and destroy the Earth. That was about 15 years ago. The Large Hadron Collider has undertaken many experiments and the Earth has survived, intact. Nothing bad has happened to the Earth or its inhabitants, whether human or otherwise.

Stories of wildlife running around in circles non-stop for 12 days or more are just rubbish! Similarly, hadron colliders do not cause earthquakes. However, they do use a lot of electricity and that's about it.